# How to pass a function?

Tags: excel, vba, function

I'm trying to reference a function that checks whether a cell exists in a report (it changes).
I've tried passing the function as an argument and all manner of other shenanigans.

I have read posts that say you can't pass as an argument and you have to call it. I don't understand how to do that.

```vb
'formats the output to look nice
Public Sub setup_headers()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim l As Range
Dim m As Range
Dim n As Range

Set l = ws2.Range("H5:H5")
Set m = ws2.Range("I5:I5")
Set n = ws2.Range("J5:J5")

ws0.Range("A1:E1").Interior.ColorIndex = 15
ws0.Range("A1:A1") = "Name"
ws0.Range("B1:B1") = "ID"
ws0.Range("C1:C1") = "Area"
ws0.Range("D1:D1") = l
ws0.Range("E1:E1") = m

If thirdSM() = True Then
    ws0.Range("F1:F1") = n
    ws0.Range("F1:F1").Interior.ColorIndex = 15
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

'is there a third safety meeting?
Public Function validate_SM(safety_meeting_worksheet As Worksheet) As Boolean

Dim validate_SM As Integer

validate_SM = safety_meeting_worksheet.Range("J:J").EntireColumn.Width

If validate_SM >= 10 Then
    thirdSM = True
Else
    thirdSM = False
End If

End Function
```

Comment: The function returns a `Boolean` value, so the caller will probably want to capture that result. You could declare a local variable and do `Dim ValidationResult As Boolean` and then `ValidationResult = validate_SM(someWorksheet)`, or just consume it directly in an `If` statement, like `If validate_SM(someWorksheet) Then ... Else ... End If`. That's all there is to it.

Comment: Side note, single-letter variable names are bad, but lowercase-L is a particular kind of evil (it looks very very close to a `1` in the VBIDE's default _Courier New_ font). Try using meaningful identifier names instead, future-you will be grateful!

Comment: Which of the worksheets is the safety meeting worksheet? `ws0` or `ws2` or something else? Depending on that information you would use the function with e.g. `If thirdSM(ws0) Then`. The signature of your function uses the same name as a variable in it i.e. it should be `Public Function thirdSM(...)...` although something like `HasThirdSM` looks a bit better. Also, use `Dim validate_SM As Double`, again something like `smWidth` would be better. The default result of the function is `False`, so you could convert the If statement to the one-liner `If validate_SM >= 10 Then thirdSM = True`.

Comment: Yeah, I was being lazy (variable 'L") since I've tried typing this out so many different ways. I was going to go back and fix those when I understood the bigger picture.

You think it sounds simple, but I don't understand what constitutes and 'argument' or a 'parameter' or whatever. All of this sounds like gibberish. I'm taking online classes but none of them explain "this goes here because X" in plain language. It's all technobabble!

Comment: @VBasic2008 ws0 is the output. ws1 is half the input and ws2 is the other half.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Calling a Function

**A Quick Fix**

- `'***` is indicating the three places where you went wrong.

```vb
Public Sub setup_headers()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim l As Range
    Dim m As Range
    Dim n As Range
    
    Set l = ws2.Range("H5:H5")
    Set m = ws2.Range("I5:I5")
    Set n = ws2.Range("J5:J5")
    
    ws0.Range("A1:E1").Interior.ColorIndex = 15
    ws0.Range("A1:A1") = "Name"
    ws0.Range("B1:B1") = "ID"
    ws0.Range("C1:C1") = "Area"
    ws0.Range("D1:D1") = l
    ws0.Range("E1:E1") = m
    
    If thirdSM(ws2) = True Then '***
    ws0.Range("F1:F1") = n
    ws0.Range("F1:F1").Interior.ColorIndex = 15
    End If
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

'is there a third safety meeting?
Public Function thirdSM(safety_meeting_worksheet As Worksheet) As Boolean '***

    Dim validate_SM As Double '***
    validate_SM = safety_meeting_worksheet.Range("J:J").EntireColumn.Width
    
    If validate_SM >= 10 Then
        thirdSM = True
    Else
        thirdSM = False
    End If

End Function
```

- Note that the above will work the same way as the following. The improvements are mostly addressing the readability, maintainability, and length of the code ('cosmetics').

**The Improvement**

- If you want to restrict a procedure to module scope, use `Private Sub` (or `Private Function`). Otherwise, just use `Sub` (or `Function`).
- `.Range("A1:A1")` is the same as `.Range("A1")`.
- If you don't have useful (descriptive) variable names instead of `l`, `m`, or `n`, then they serve no purpose and you should get rid of them and e.g. use  `ws0.Range("D1").Value = ws2.Range("H5").Value`.
- If you're writing values to a range, then use the `Value` property to make it obvious, e.g. `ws0.Range("A1").Value = "Name"`.
- `If thirdSM(ws2) = True Then` is the same as `If thirdSM(ws2) Then`.
- `.Range("J:J")` is the same as `.Columns("J")`.
- Use meaningful variable and procedure names using *CapitalCase* or *camelCase* without underscores.
- Looking at the function, it has one argument and it is called `SafetyMeetingWorksheet`. It needs a worksheet-type parameter. Now looking at the sub, the function is being passed the parameter `ws2`. You could say (inaccurately) the function's first (and only) argument's parameter is set to `ws2`.
- When declaring a variable, it has an initial value. So does a function. In this case, since it is a boolean, its initial value is `False` i.e. if you don't write any code into it, it will always return `False`. So you don't have to use the line `thirdSM = False` since it's already false and you can write the If statement in one line.

```vb
Sub SetupHeadersImprovement()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    ws0.Range("A1:E1").Interior.ColorIndex = 15
    
    ws0.Range("A1").Value = "Name"
    ws0.Range("B1").Value = "ID"
    ws0.Range("C1").Value = "Area"
    ws0.Range("D1").Value = ws2.Range("H5").Value
    ws0.Range("E1").Value = ws2.Range("I5").Value
    
    If HasThirdSafetyMeeting(ws2) Then
        ws0.Range("F1").Interior.ColorIndex = 15
        ws0.Range("F1").Value = ws2.Range("J5").Value
    End If
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Function HasThirdSafetyMeeting( _
    ByVal SafetyMeetingWorksheet As Worksheet) _
As Boolean
    
    Dim SafetyMeetingWidth As Double
    SafetyMeetingWidth = SafetyMeetingWorksheet.Columns("J").Width
    
    If SafetyMeetingWidth >= 10 Then HasThirdSafetyMeeting = True

End Function
```

**More Improvements**

- Introducing Constants

  - To easily change certain values in one place, at the beginning of the code, especially if they are repeated in the code many times.
- Introducing the With Statement

  - To improve readability.
- Using Color Instead of ColorIndex

  - To always use the same color no matter which color palette is used.
- Realizing the Redundancy of the Function

  - It does only a simple thing so there's no use for it.

```vb
Sub SetupHeadersNoFunction()

    Const HIGHLIGHT_COLOR As Long = 12632256 ' gray
    Const SAFETY_MEETING_COLUMN_WIDTH As Double = 10
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    With ws0.Range("A1:F1")
        .Columns(1).Value = "Name"
        .Columns(2).Value = "ID"
        .Columns(3).Value = "Area"
        .Columns(4).Value = ws2.Range("H5").Value
        .Columns(5).Value = ws2.Range("I5").Value
        .Resize(, 5).Interior.Color = HIGHLIGHT_COLOR
        With .Columns(6)
            If ws2.Columns("J").Width >= SAFETY_MEETING_COLUMN_WIDTH Then
                .Value = ws2.Range("J5").Value
                .Interior.Color = HIGHLIGHT_COLOR
            End If
        End With
    End With
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```